# организация, структура кода из 3 модулей на nodejs

Tags: node.js

Имеется несколько модулей
**Вебсокет**
**БД**
**Дискорд бот**

Также есть модуль
Обработка сообщений от вебсокета, сохранение в бд и отправка в дискорд бот. То есть взаимодействие со всеми модулями

Как организовать связь между ними? Я написал их используя классы. Но я не могу использовать один класс в другом классе, так как они оба инициализируют друг друга. Хотелось бы сделать их более не зависимы друг от друга.

Например. Сообщение от сокета -> используем БД, обрабатываем, отправляем в дс и отвечаем сокету